# docker: Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists UTC

Tags: docker

i try to run this command to create a new container,but i see some problem

```
docker run -d --name php-test-docker -v /home/docker-data/php-test-docker:/var/www/  -p 9009:9000 -p 1219:1215 php7.3-centos7.6:v1.4 "/bin/sh -c sbin/php-fpm"
```

The problem is that i get this error from this command:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /home/docker/overlay2/b6ad71e5392ce15ddc16d394f69f38a21622f606a05719dfcebc553560811632/merged/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: What is in your image's Dockerfile?  (Does it have unnecessary `VOLUME` directives, perhaps?)

Comment: Yes, it does have some problems. I'll just use a new DockerFile to execute it.